# Make a Column Based on Pandas Timeseries Minutes OHLCV Dataframe Where New Column Fills with Corresponding Day's First Value from a Specific Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, time-series

My initial **Pandas Dataframe** is:

```
                               Open      High        Low         Close      Volume
2021-11-19 09:30:00-05:00   16549.50    16559.25    16516.25    16530.25    20198.0
2021-11-19 09:35:00-05:00   16530.50    16562.00    16525.50    16556.50    11274.0
...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
2021-11-21 09:35:00-05:00   16556.50    16564.00    16544.00    16563.75    7632.0
2021-11-21 09:40:00-05:00   16563.75    16583.25    16555.50    16580.50    10404.0
...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
2021-11-22 09:50:00-05:00   16580.25    16589.00    16571.25    16587.50    7997.0
2021-11-22 09:55:00-05:00   16580.25    16589.00    16571.25    16587.50    7997.0
...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
```

My desired **Dataframe** from the above Dataframe:

```
                             Open       Days Open
2021-11-19 09:30:00-05:00   16549.50    16549.50
2021-11-19 09:35:00-05:00   16530.50    16549.50
...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
2021-11-21 09:35:00-05:00   16556.50    16556.50
2021-11-21 09:40:00-05:00   16563.75    16556.50
...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
2021-11-22 09:50:00-05:00   16580.25    16580.25
2021-11-22 09:55:00-05:00   16680.25    16580.25
...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
```

I tried the below code and get the first row for every day.

```
In [1]: df.groupby([df.index.date], axis=0).first()
```

**Edit:**

Here is my **solution**. May be there are better solutions than this solution.

```
#Here df is our initial ohlcv dataframe

#Groupby date and timestamp
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby([df.index.date, df.index], axis=0)['Open'].first())

#Make Timestamp as column
df1.reset_index(level=1, inplace=True)

#Groupby date and get the first row for every date. Then change set the Timestamp column as index 
df1 = df1.groupby(level=[0]).first().set_index('level_1')

#Change the coulmn name Open to Days Open
df1.rename(columns={'Open':"Day's Open"}, inplace=True)

#Change the index name level_1 to None
df1.index.name = None

#Make a dataframe with Open column from initial ohlcv dataframe 
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df['Open'])

#Make column named Days Open with Nan value
df2["Day's Open"]=np.nan

#Update the datafarame with daily open data
df2.update(df1)

#Fill the NAN value with last non-nan value
df2.fillna(method='ffill')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my **solution**. May be there are better solutions than this solution.

```
#Here df is our initial ohlcv dataframe

#Groupby date and timestamp
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby([df.index.date, df.index], axis=0)['Open'].first())

#Make Timestamp as column
df1.reset_index(level=1, inplace=True)

#Groupby date and get the first row for every date. Then change set the Timestamp column as index 
df1 = df1.groupby(level=[0]).first().set_index('level_1')

#Change the coulmn name Open to Days Open
df1.rename(columns={'Open':"Day's Open"}, inplace=True)

#Change the index name level_1 to None
df1.index.name = None

#Make a dataframe with Open column from initial ohlcv dataframe 
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df['Open'])

#Make column named Days Open with Nan value
df2["Day's Open"]=np.nan

#Update the datafarame with daily open data
df2.update(df1)

#Fill the NAN values with last non-nan value
df2.fillna(method='ffill')
```